# Запуск промисов по новой

Tags: javascript

В общем хочу запускать по новой промис.

пробовал вот так

```
do {
Promise.all([getTimeLabel()])
    .then(timerGo => {

        let handle;
        let timeOut = compareLabelTime();
        if (handle) clearTimeout(handle);

    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
console.log('Запустил промис поновой');
}while (true);
```

не совсем то что нужно, промис всегда Рестартует
Пробовал вот так

```
const getALL =()=> {
Promise.all([getTimeLabel()])
    .then(timerGo => {
         compareLabelTime();
    })
    .then(handle=>{
        clearTimeout(handle);
       return getALL();
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
getALL();
```

Не могу понять как по новой перезапустить этот промис после последнего resolve?